# JavaFX resizing root stackpane

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

i'd like to have a StackPane as the root node, it makes overlay effects easy.

But by using a stackpane as the root, inner controls can move out of the window.
In the following example you can see the controls moving out of the window , 
if you shrink the window small enough, e.g. both the menubar and the listview go out to the left. I want to prevent this, how can i do that?

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("controls move out of window :(");

        Menu menu = new Menu("Menu");
        MenuBar menubar = new MenuBar(menu);

        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Args, it moves away."));

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setTop(menubar);
        borderPane.setLeft(listView);

        StackPane rootStackPane = new StackPane(borderPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootStackPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**Update:**

setting the alignment for the BorderPane inside the StackPane seems to help:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setTitle("controls stay in window :)");

    Menu menu = new Menu("Menu");
    MenuBar menubar = new MenuBar(menu);

    ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("it stays!"));

    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.setTop(menubar);
    borderPane.setLeft(listView);

    StackPane rootStackPane = new StackPane(borderPane);
    StackPane.setAlignment(borderPane, Pos.TOP_LEFT);
    Scene scene = new Scene(rootStackPane);
    stage.setScene(scene);

    stage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place your stack in a [Group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html) and bind the stack's preferred size to the scene's preferred size.

[image: centered larger]
[image: centered smaller]

As you can see from the second image, the overlay is not centered on the visible screen, it is centered on the StackPane.  The StackPane's minimum size will be the minimum size of it's largest component (even if it overflows the screen), so the overlay is centered on that.  To find out minimum sizes of things, you could use either design the UI in [SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxscenebuilder-info-2157684.html) or debug the UI using [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("controls stay in window :)");

        Menu menu = new Menu("Menu");
        MenuBar menubar = new MenuBar();
        menubar.getMenus().add(menu);

        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("Args, it moves away."));

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setTop(menubar);
        borderPane.setLeft(listView);
        borderPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: palegreen;");

        Node overlayContent = new Label("centered");
        StackPane stack = new StackPane(borderPane, overlayContent);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(stack));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        stack.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
        stack.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this works. After reading your _centered on the StackPane_ i had an idea.
What about setting the alignment of the StackPane to Pos.TOP_LEFT? 
see updated question.
Here it works and without a Group node and the binding of the StackPane.

Comment: `StackPane.setAlignment(borderPane, Pos.TOP_LEFT);` works and is a better solution IMO.

Comment: If you wish, you can edit your question, remove the update and [post a self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) marking it correct.